# RO reverse osmosis filters need replacing?

Tags: water

I tested the water & there's copper in it (about 1.0) but everything else is good. Is it possible that used filters might fail to filter only one contaminate & still filter others?

If this is unlikely then perhaps I need a better model? Ours is a membrane plus 3 filters from Culligan.

There is no decrease in water flow so I believe the membrane is still good. We only use about 1 gal. a day so I don't go by the recommended "replace every 6-9 months".

Comment: Do you have copper water lines? RO water leaches materials out of copper pipes and causes pinhole failures over many years.

Comment: There's no copper between the RO system and its dedicated faucet. But a side question: if copper leaches so much why is it used in plumbing where water is consumed?

Comment: Regular water not super pure like RO treated water doesn’t cause the problem. Demonized water used in wafer manufacture eats copper really fast; they have to use stainless & Teflon tubing to maintain the purity.

Comment: "Demonized"? Surely you mean deionized?

Answer (score 1):

Any water filter will need to be replaced with a new one eventually. This is because the filter medium gets clogged from the particles it was designed to capture. It is best to check the replacement schedule according to the filter manufacturer. A good guess is roughly every 3-5 months if the date hasn't been written on the filter case.

There are several filters available and each is specific for according to what needs to be removed from the water. There are also "all-in-one" type filters that can remove several maladies if needed. You can also upgrade your R.O filter by adding-on additional cartridges for additional filters. When the new filter has been installed and checked for leaks allow the system to flush any factory residuals by running the water for several minutes before using the water for ingesting.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will have to study our setup some more. It appears that (hot) water from the filter housing which has not passed through the membrane is being mixed with water that has, in the faucet. But I could be completely wrong.

Comment: As for the filters, I will hold on for more info on why only copper is showing in the test & maybe buy another test kit to test the pre-treated water.

Comment: most potable water is going to have miniscule elements which is allowed by municipal health standards. Agreed that isn't reassuring, but even the most redundant (filter after filter after filter...)  and elaborate filtering system can't remove all impurities. The "1.0" in your question, I'm guessing, is the measurement of copper particulate measured at 1 ppb or (parts per billion)?  Just so you know some copper is needed for the human body to function properly. Here's the CDC's take:  http://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/PHS/PHS.asp?id=204&tid=37

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's 1.0 ppm or 1,000 ppb. Since the Federal max is 1,300 ppb I figure 1,000 is kinda high.

Comment: I think you mean 1.0 ppb (billion) or 1,000 ppm (million)?

Comment: No you're thinking of the inverse where 1,000m = 1b.